# How can I get acces token and refresh token in keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, access-token

Is there any way I can get contents of the post request for access tokens(http://localhost:8484/auth/realms/my_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token) and get both tokens on the screen in get request?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no such api from Keycloak where you can get both access token and refresh token in a get request, it is possible only via the POST(api).
If your only intention is to view the token's for development then you can use chrome dev tools, or log them in your spring boot app.

Answer (score 0):

If you POST get tokens (access and refresh) this command, you can get  both tokens.

#1 curl demo

```
curl -v \
-d "client_id=admin-cli" \
-d "username=user" \
-d "password=1234" \
-d "grant_type=password" \
-X \
POST "http://localhost:8484/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token" | jq
```

This is result

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJrTXNKN25mdUFpYWFBYXhZeFp2WXo3WWVFaVh6Nk5hZzV6LXMyazFreUpNIn0.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.BzPrRNdgdyDgg7Y0BNNuAVDfC9NBOyo97JBpw-kfRr-NRPfcP27ch3FONC108v4GQqOLTLF0Z5y6SoQr2BcX9ZFqBm5d8_tSn2XSVSoxWh_ci91PYzfs4656_QLV2TBcTPrW69Z-5oCEUEGZjpKW2UsavEonwTlop80xoDVTpvfgfq-pv0gh8tX6260weynIxSALiy8srFs6ExHp8IGqp-bKNPXM35nM9BX9gPgKPrrbe-IenXO37ESazubqhdtznzcCEDFrTNnOKR87hiFcInx28o2sBMhcDiZxPbaIfNhCpENxnoeNPHFnVA6wayjaJSiBxKVO8EMVaOSlDTRS9w",
  "expires_in": 300,
  "refresh_expires_in": 1800,
  "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJhMTdkM2U5Yi1kMThlLTQyOGQtYTUxYS0xYzdiMzhkYTkxYjgifQ.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.UDV1fBhW8I7E9IELNK7XOvpy-6FJ_Bdir1wujYNvK_U",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "not-before-policy": 0,
  "session_state": "e3b98ba2-b635-41f1-84a9-e95c6bd6f3a9",
  "scope": "profile email"
}
```

#2 You can see the content via [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)

copy from #1's token , paste to Encoded section

for access token content

```
{
  "exp": 1665655584,
  "iat": 1665655284,
  "jti": "f40abf0c-f069-4aab-87ae-7c4009ff7d65",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8484/auth/realms/test",
  "sub": "3912c6d0-f210-4bed-8c56-70364d228add",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "session_state": "e3b98ba2-b635-41f1-84a9-e95c6bd6f3a9",
  "scope": "profile email",
  "sid": "e3b98ba2-b635-41f1-84a9-e95c6bd6f3a9",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "user",
  "email": "user@test.com"
}
```

for refresh token content

```
{
  "exp": 1665657084,
  "iat": 1665655284,
  "jti": "b951054a-b59d-4621-a08f-0319fdb75e06",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8484/auth/realms/test",
  "aud": "http://localhost:8484/auth/realms/test",
  "sub": "3912c6d0-f210-4bed-8c56-70364d228add",
  "typ": "Refresh",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "session_state": "e3b98ba2-b635-41f1-84a9-e95c6bd6f3a9",
  "scope": "profile email",
  "sid": "e3b98ba2-b635-41f1-84a9-e95c6bd6f3a9"
}
```

Decoding JWT in bash command

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST "http://localhost:8484/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=user' \
--data-urlencode 'password=1234' | jq -r '.access_token')
```

Confirm access token

```
echo $ACCESS_TOKEN
```

```
jwtd() {
    if [[ -x $(command -v jq) ]]; then
         jq -R 'split(".") | .[0],.[1] | @base64d | fromjson' <<< "${1}"
         echo "Signature: $(echo "${1}" | awk -F'.' '{print $3}')"
    fi
}

jwtd $ACCESS_TOKEN
```

result

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "kMsJ7nfuAiaaAaxYxZvYz7YeEiXz6Nag5z-s2k1kyJM"
}
{
  "exp": 1665656835,
  "iat": 1665656535,
  "jti": "6fdcd375-e721-4646-b725-4f5f23d8b103",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8484/auth/realms/test",
  "sub": "3912c6d0-f210-4bed-8c56-70364d228add",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "session_state": "f0353bdd-0a08-49eb-bc2a-111ceb59dc56",
  "scope": "profile email",
  "sid": "f0353bdd-0a08-49eb-bc2a-111ceb59dc56",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "user",
  "email": "user@test.com"
}
```

Same way to get refresh token

```
REFRESH_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST "http://localhost:8484/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=user' \
--data-urlencode 'password=1234' | jq -r '.refresh_token')
```

```
jwtd $REFRESH_TOKEN
```

result

```
$ jwtd $REFRESH_TOKEN
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "a17d3e9b-d18e-428d-a51a-1c7b38da91b8"
}
{
  "exp": 1665658687,
  "iat": 1665656887,
  "jti": "287a7f90-1435-44e6-b8c8-417eda935382",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8484/auth/realms/test",
  "aud": "http://localhost:8484/auth/realms/test",
  "sub": "3912c6d0-f210-4bed-8c56-70364d228add",
  "typ": "Refresh",
  "azp": "admin-cli",
  "session_state": "4beb4f1d-fb56-42b6-99ea-d13281b8db3f",
  "scope": "profile email",
  "sid": "4beb4f1d-fb56-42b6-99ea-d13281b8db3f"
}
Signature: JAyDz4qS9Jvi4u8sHS68NPP8721MzlQXPXNaIgtD7v8
```